# Banner AD - URL Referrer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, referrer

We have a website that has a banner ad we want to link to a special promotion page. The challenge is that we only want users who clicked the ad to be able to get the promotion discount.

I've heard people use javascript url.referrer or other approaches and personally I am not too sure how the best way to implement this would be. Should we trust the url referrer?

Basically we don't need anything to sophisticated or complex, just want to prevent users from accessing the promo page via copy/paste sharing of the link.

Comment: I would just show it for all users, however, if you must restrict it to only users that clicked the banner, have the banner hit an intermediary page and sets a cookie, then redirects to the promo page. On the promo page, check for said cookie. if it doesn't exist, redirect them elsewhere. this should be done all server-side.

Comment: i don't know of any ad vendors that would be cool with you doing what your describe...

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, it's our own banner ad and not any vendor's ad.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what is the matter?

Users will get to that promo page on one way or another. It does not make any difference if the direct link to that page is shared, or if the link to a page is shared that contains your banner.

Also, think of the legal stuff: If you offer any promo discount on that page, you are required to deliver that promo. So your page would have to be dynamic and only print that promo offer if the requirements have been met - that way you'd get promo customers only via banner link, and more customers without promo. Is it really worth it to probably annoy users because they want to become your paying customer, but clicked the wrong link?

Anyways, the referrer is the only thing you can use here. But also think about the users who don't send referrers, because they chose to configure their browser that way.

Comment: Using the referrer doesn't seem to be the best approach and as Kevin B said the server side solution he's recommending makes more sense. The banner is being placed on another site in their member area, so we only want members of their site to have access to the promo and nobody else.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while doing some search, I thought to share what I think although this is an old question.

I believe your best approach is to use http only cookie, if you can place a pixel iframe in the banner of your ad, this iframe is under your domain and it places a cookie with some unique identifier created by your server, this cookie will be sent with the request once the user press on the banner and it is redirected to your page, checking for the cookie if the value is ok this would be an indication the customer was redirected by the banner.